# Infinite Loop using a Long data type

Tags: java, for-loop, long-integer

Im currently doing some project euler problems and Im getting an infinite loop for the For Loop using Long data types. I normally use Integers and dont have much experience with this data type.? Could anyone advise how to solve this?

The Question is: The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int temp = 15;
        long number = 600851475143L;
        ArrayList<Integer> primeFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int largest = 0;

        for(long i=2L; i<number; i++)
        {
            if(temp % i == 0)
            {
                if(isPrime(i))
                {
                    primeFactors.add((int) i);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Integer pF:primeFactors)
        {
            if(pF>largest)
            {
                largest = pF;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 is: " + largest);
    }

    // A prime number is a natural number greater than 1 that is not a product of two smaller natural numbers.
    private static boolean isPrime(long number)
    {
        if (number <= 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually observing an *infinite* loop rather than just the fact that you're iterating more than 600 billion times, with each of those iterations executing an inner loop? (Basically, I believe the point of the question is to avoid using this sort of brute force...)

Answer (score 0):

Like Jon Skeet mentioned in the comment, point of this question and a lot of other project euler questions is that the calculations will end up taking way too long time to solve if you try to solve them with brute force. Thus, you need to find a more clever way. For some of the project euler questions there exists formulas that you can use to get to the answer and you can just implement them. For others, you need to think of a better way of solving the problem yourself.

So your problems are not related to data type.

In general, project euler problems can be considered math problems at least as much as programming problems.